# How to pull from the remote environment

Tags: ssh, putty, remote

I want to run sqlplus after remote login how can I do this?

I'm using:

> `wshShell.Run "C:\putty.exe -t -ssh -l someuser -pw pass -m c:remote.cmd 10.100.5.70"`

Contents of `c:remote.cmd`

> `cd /home/someuser;./run_script.sh;echo;echo 'Press any key to continue......';read var;exit;`

I need to pull from the remote ENV, but the notty option is preventing that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would need `c:\remote.cmd` instead

Comment: works fine without the \

Comment: it works now, i'm just having to create the environment variables by exporting them so my remote.cmd now has a few export commands